# System.Text.Json and polymorphic code: not working with WebApi controllers

Tags: c#, polymorphism, asp.net-core-webapi, system.text.json, .net-7.0

With .NET 7.0 being released, `System.Text.Json` is supposed to support polymorphic code. Unfortunately, it seems like it can't be used out of the box when you need to return a derived type's instance from a controller's method. For instance, suppose the following model:

```
public class Base {}

public class Derived1: Base  { }

public class Derived2: Base  { }
```

Suppose also that we've got  the following dynamic type info resolver:

```
public class JsonHierarchyTypeInfoResolver : DefaultJsonTypeInfoResolver {    
    public override JsonTypeInfo GetTypeInfo(Type type, JsonSerializerOptions options) {
        var jsonTypeInfo = base.GetTypeInfo(type, options);

        if( typeof(Base) == jsonTypeInfo.Type ) {
            jsonTypeInfo.PolymorphismOptions = new( ) {
                                                          TypeDiscriminatorPropertyName = "$type", 
                                                          IgnoreUnrecognizedTypeDiscriminators = true,
                                                          UnknownDerivedTypeHandling = JsonUnknownDerivedTypeHandling.FailSerialization,
                                                          DerivedTypes = {
                                                                             new JsonDerivedType(typeof(Derived1), typeof(Derived1).AssemblyQualifiedName!),
                                                                             new JsonDerivedType(typeof(Derived2), typeof(Derived2).AssemblyQualifiedName!)
                                                                         }
                                                      };
            
        }
        return jsonTypeInfo;
    }
}
```

And then, it's used in the app by doing something like this:

```
builder.Services.AddControllers( )
       .AddJsonOptions(options => {
                           options.JsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true;
                           options.JsonSerializerOptions.TypeInfoResolver = new JsonHierarchyTypeInfoResolver( );
                       });
```

Let's also assume that we've got a simple controller with a simple method that looks like this:

```
[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]")]
public class DEMOController : ControllerBase {
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult<Base> GetAsync() {
        var derived = new Derived1(  );
        return Ok(derived);
    }
}
```

Whenever the method is called, it will not generate json with the type descriminator as I expected it to. It seems like the problem lies with the `SystemTextJsonOutputFormatter` when it tries to serialize the object with the following code:

```
await JsonSerializer.SerializeAsync(responseStream, context.Object, objectType, SerializerOptions, httpContext.RequestAborted);
```

and here's how `objectType` is initialized:

```
// context.ObjectType reflects the declared model type when specified.
// For polymorphic scenarios where the user declares a return type, but returns a derived type,
// we want to serialize all the properties on the derived type. This keeps parity with
// the behavior you get when the user does not declare the return type and with Json.Net at least at the top level.
var objectType = context.Object?.GetType() ?? context.ObjectType ?? typeof(object);
```

Since the method uses the derived type, the custom info type resolver won't be able to do its magic. Am I missing something? Is this a known issue? Does this mean that I should keep using json.net instead of trying to migrate to System.Text.Json?

Comment: Looks like this is a known limitation of, or issue with, `SystemTextJsonOutputFormatter`, namely that it serializes the actual type, not the declared type.  See: [System.Text.Json Polymorphic Type Resolving Issue #77532](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/77532).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The type which ASP.NET Core resolves for `GetAsync` would be `Derived1` which does not have any polymorphism info, so it will not add any polymorphic serialization data. One solution is to add polymorphism info for every type in the hierarchy:

```cs
public class JsonHierarchyTypeInfoResolver : DefaultJsonTypeInfoResolver
{
    public override JsonTypeInfo GetTypeInfo(Type type, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        var jsonTypeInfo = base.GetTypeInfo(type, options);
        // if type inherits or is Base
        if (jsonTypeInfo.Type.IsAssignableTo(typeof(Base)))
        {
            jsonTypeInfo.PolymorphismOptions = new()
            {
                TypeDiscriminatorPropertyName = "$type",
                IgnoreUnrecognizedTypeDiscriminators = true,
                UnknownDerivedTypeHandling = JsonUnknownDerivedTypeHandling.FailSerialization,
            };

            var derivedTypes = new[]
                {
                    typeof(WeatherForecastController.Derived1),
                    typeof(WeatherForecastController.Derived2)
                }
                .Where(t => jsonTypeInfo.Type.IsAssignableTo(t)) // add only appropriate types
                .Select(t => new JsonDerivedType(t, t.AssemblyQualifiedName!));
            foreach (var derivedType in derivedTypes)
            {
                jsonTypeInfo.PolymorphismOptions.DerivedTypes.Add(derivedType);
            }
        }

        return jsonTypeInfo;
    }
}
```