# Why missing $type when serialize generic with JsonDerivedType?

Tags: c#, json, system.text.json

Here are my codes:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{        
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Debug.WriteLine(JsonSerializer.Serialize<TestModel>(new TestModel() { Name = "123", Time = DateTime.Now }));
        Debug.WriteLine(JsonSerializer.Serialize<TestModelWithGeneric<int>>(new TestModelWithGeneric<int>() { Name = "123", Time = DateTime.Now ,Value=1}));
        Debug.WriteLine(JsonSerializer.Serialize<TestModelWithGeneric<string>>(new TestModelWithGeneric<string>() { Name = "123", Time = DateTime.Now, Value = "123" }));
    }
    [JsonDerivedType(typeof(TestModel), typeDiscriminator: "Base")]
    [JsonDerivedType(typeof(TestModelWithGeneric<int>), typeDiscriminator: "TestModelWithInt")]
    [JsonDerivedType(typeof(TestModelWithGeneric<string>), typeDiscriminator: "TestModelWithString")]
    public class TestModel {
        public string Name{ get; set; }
        public DateTime Time { get; set; }
    }
    public class TestModelWithGeneric<T> :TestModel{ 
        public T Value { get; set; }
    }
}
```

The output is:

```
{"$type":"Base","Name":"123","Time":"2023-12-04T15:29:49.7867248+08:00"}
{"Value":1,"Name":"123","Time":"2023-12-04T15:29:49.8314012+08:00"}
{"Value":"123","Name":"123","Time":"2023-12-04T15:29:49.8354174+08:00"}
```

As you see, when there is a generic type, it always missing $type that JsonDerivedType no working.

What's wrong with my code?

The framework I am working is .Net8 .

Comment: The reason is the same as in case of web APIs (at least in some previous versions) - you are using derived type as generic parameter and `System.Text.Json` serializer will not resolve the type info from it. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74780668/2501279) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75751184/2501279) answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TestModelWithGeneric<T>` does not have any polymorphic serialization info added so the `System.Text.Json` serializer will not apply it when the serialized generic type is resolved as `TestModelWithGeneric<T>` (generic types are resolved at compile time). You can specify type explicitly:

```
Console.WriteLine(JsonSerializer.Serialize<TestModel>(new TestModel() { Name = "123", Time = DateTime.Now }));
Console.WriteLine(JsonSerializer.Serialize<TestModel>(new TestModelWithGeneric<int>() { Name = "123", Time = DateTime.Now ,Value=1}));
Console.WriteLine(JsonSerializer.Serialize<TestModel>(new TestModelWithGeneric<string>() { Name = "123", Time = DateTime.Now, 
     Value = "123" }));
```

But this is not ideal option because it is easy to miss calls (for example the call `JsonSerializer.Serialize(new TestModelWithGeneric<string>() ...)` will infer the "incorrect" type of `TestModelWithGeneric<string>`). Another option would be to use custom `IJsonTypeInfoResolver`. For example simple one can look like (handles only `TestModel` but can be expanded for more generic handling):

```
public class JsonHierarchyTypeInfoResolver : DefaultJsonTypeInfoResolver
{
    public override JsonTypeInfo GetTypeInfo(Type type, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        var result = base.GetTypeInfo(type, options);
        if (type != typeof(TestModel) && type.IsAssignableTo(typeof(TestModel)))
        {
            var baseInfo = base.GetTypeInfo(typeof(TestModel), options);
            foreach (var derivedType in baseInfo.PolymorphismOptions.DerivedTypes)
            {
                if (derivedType.DerivedType.IsAssignableTo(type))
                {
                    result.PolymorphismOptions ??= new JsonPolymorphismOptions();
                    result.PolymorphismOptions.DerivedTypes.Add(derivedType);
                }
            }
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

And usage:

```
var options = new JsonSerializerOptions
{
    TypeInfoResolver = new JsonHierarchyTypeInfoResolver()
};
Console.WriteLine(JsonSerializer.Serialize(
    new TestModel { Name = "123", Time = DateTime.Now }
    , options));
Console.WriteLine(JsonSerializer.Serialize(
    new TestModelWithGeneric<int> { Name = "123", Time = DateTime.Now ,Value=1}
    , options));
Console.WriteLine(JsonSerializer.Serialize(
    new TestModelWithGeneric<string> { Name = "123", Time = DateTime.Now, Value = "123" }
    , options));
```

Which results in:

```
{"$type":"Base","Name":"123","Time":"2023-12-04T12:37:43.9072465+03:00"}
{"$type":"TestModelWithInt","Value":1,"Name":"123","Time":"2023-12-04T12:37:44.1239771+03:00"}       
{"$type":"TestModelWithString","Value":"123","Name":"123","Time":"2023-12-04T12:37:44.1282147+03:00"}
```

See also:

- [How can I serialize a multi-level polymorphic type hierarchy with System.Text.Json in .NET 7?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74604551/2501279)
- [System.Text.Json and polymorphic code: not working with WebApi controllers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74777953/2501279)

Answer (score 2):

Problem solved! According to the [How to serialize properties of derived classes with `System.Text.Json`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/polymorphism?Pivots=dotnet-8-0) doc:

> For polymorphic serialization to work, the type of the serialized value should be that of the polymorphic base type. This includes using the base type as the generic type parameter when serializing root-level values, as the declared type of serialized properties, or as the collection element in serialized collections.

I should call `JsonSerializer.Serialize<T>` with explicit `TestModel` provided for the generic argument:

```
 Debug.WriteLine(JsonSerializer.Serialize<TestModel>(new TestModel() { Name = "123", Time = DateTime.Now }));
 Debug.WriteLine(JsonSerializer.Serialize<TestModel>(new TestModelWithGeneric<int>() { Name = "123", Time = DateTime.Now ,Value=1}));
 Debug.WriteLine(JsonSerializer.Serialize<TestModel>(new TestModelWithGeneric<string>() { Name = "123", Time = DateTime.Now, 
     Value = "123" }));
```

Then it works now!

Comment: Please add a little narrative explanation. An answer shouldn't be "here, play spot the difference between the code here and the code in the question". That's not a fun game for anyone.

Comment: Took a liberty to change wording a bit. Feel free to revert if it is deemed not a correct/good one.